# converting time Stamp to date and Date to Time stamp formats

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp

Date is: 10/02/2014 (DD/MM/YYYY).
How to convert it into Timestamp format.??

And how to change the format of date.When i write the code like:

```
var current_date=new Date();  -->i got result like MM/DD/YYYY format.
```

I want DD/MM/YYYY format for current date.

Comment: 10/02/2014 **is** a [*timestamp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp). ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dateFormat](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) library.

```
var current_date = new Date();
dateFormat(current_date, "dd/mm/yyyy");
```

This returns date in "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

Comment: Thanks you For your response bro.Its working well.@sainath batthala

Answer (score 1):

By "timestamp" I guess you mean the time value, like `1391954400000`.

To convert a date string to a Date you need to parse it. Use a library or short function. You can then get the time value, which represents a number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z:

```js
/* Parse date sting in d/m/y format
** @param {string} s - date string in d/m/y format
**                     separator can be any non–digit character
** @returns {Date} If s is an invalid date, returned
**                 Date has time value of NaN (invalid date)
*/
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[1], b[0]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]? d : new Date(NaN);
}

// Valid date
console.log(parseDMY('10/02/2014').getTime());

// Invalid date
console.log(parseDMY('14/20/2016').getTime());
```

There are also plenty of libraries for formatting dates (e.g. [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) does parsing and formatting), or again, if you have just one format, a simple function will do:

```js
/* Return date string in format dd/mm/yyy
** @param {Date} d - date to format, default to today
** @returns {string} date in dd/mm/yyyy format
*/
function formatDMY(d) {
  // Default to today
  d = d || new Date();
  return ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + '/' +
         ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' +
         ('000' + d.getFullYear()).slice(-4);
}

console.log(formatDMY());
console.log(formatDMY(new Date(2016,1,29)));
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are

```
var current_date=new Date();
var timestamp = current_date.getTime();
var formatted_date = current_date.getDate() + "/" + current_date.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + current_date.getFullYear()
```